# How can polarisation be "frozen into" a material?

Tags: polarization

Section 4.1.4 ("Polarization") of Introduction to Electrodynamics by David J. Griffiths says the following:

> It's even possible in some materials to "freeze in" polarization, so that it persists after the field is removed.

It does not, however, go into any more detail on this. How is this possible?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Polarization requires long-range order in a solid, so you heat the solid to a sufficiently high temperature to enable solid-state diffusion (which means atomic rearrangements) and then apply the polarizing field. While holding the field on, you allow the sample to cool back to room temperature, which shuts off atomic diffusion and de-ordering of the polarized structure. In this way, the long-range order you imposed on the solid with the field while it was hot then persists after you turn off the original field.

As long as the sample is not heated up again (which enables the long-range order to be jiggled away by thermally-activated diffusion), the polarization is thus "frozen in".

Comment: I think you explain how to achieve this very well. But how does it stay "frozen"?

Comment: @AaronStevens, will edit my answer. -NN